# Why does Google AppEngine have two primary keys, 'key' and 'id/name'?

Tags: google-app-engine

If you leave one or the other empty, or don't specify in your Entity, it creates a key/id for that entity anyways, as seen in the admin console datastore viewer.

Bonus question: Why can't you get the ID for an Entity object after you put() it? `entity.getProperty("id")` returns null. Key objects cannot be serialized so cannot be used by GWT.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys

Answer (score 5):

Entities have a Key, and Keys (of persisted entities) have either auto-assigned ids, or programmer-supplied names. The name/id is a property of the Key, not a property of the Entity.

Instead of `entity.getProperty("id")` in Java you write `entity.getKey().getId()` (or `.getName()` if you gave the key a name).

The lower-level details are in:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key

`

Comment: Would `KeyFactory.createKey(kind, id)` be the way to find an Entity based on its id #?

Comment: Not directly. That just creates a Key. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Retrieving_an_entity for how to go from having a Key to having the Entity that it refers to.